PrimeVue datatable. Possible way to place the sortable icon to another line in the header
As the title suggests, is there any possible way to separate the name and the "sortable" icon and move said icon to another line? (bottom)
I have been using the "Presort" in the documents (https://primevue.org/datatable/) to try and figure this out:
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2FApp.vue
Is there some sort of tag/class/code to use in the line to put that spacing mentioned?
<Column field="code" header="Code" sortable style="width: 20%"></Column>

Since it is not clear from the link. Maybe something like that is intended, or am I mistaken?

<div class="card">
    <DataTable
      :value="products"
      sortField="price"
      :sortOrder="-1"
      tableStyle="min-width: 50rem"
    >
      <Column
        :pt="{
          columnHeaderContent: { style: { 'flex-direction': 'column' } },
        }"
        field="code"
        header="Code"
        sortable
        style="width: 20%"
      ></Column>
      <Column
        :pt="{
          columnHeaderContent: { style: { 'flex-direction': 'column' } },
        }"
        field="name"
        header="Name"
        sortable
        style="width: 20%"
      ></Column>
      <Column
        :pt="{
          columnHeaderContent: { style: { 'flex-direction': 'column' } },
        }"
        field="price"
        header="Price"
        :sortable="true"
      >
        <template #body="slotProps">
          {{ formatCurrency(slotProps.data.price) }}
        </template>
      </Column>
      <Column
        field="category"
        header="Category"
        sortable
        style="width: 20%"
      ></Column>
      <Column
        field="quantity"
        header="Quantity"
        sortable
        style="width: 20%"
      ></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bwsjal?file=src%2FApp.vue
Best regards.
